# saving a geometry in postgis from blender

Tags: postgis, blender, wkt, polyhedra

Say I have a cube or more complex closed triangulated object in Blender, how would I be able to store this in postgis?

Postgis stores 3D geometry via well-known text (wkt) as a polyhedral or tin. Is there any way to get a blender object into postgis?

Answer (score 0):

You read blenders data and create insert statements for postgresql. As blender contains a python interpreter, you can [run a python script in blender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html) that sends the data to postgresql.

The first step is installing a python postgresql module, such as [psycopg](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg3/) that can be used within blender. There are [several options](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75091/935) for this, including adding a path to [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

Once you can run a python script in blender that can talk to a postgresql server, read blenders [mesh data](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Mesh.html) to generate the insert statements.

```
pg_insert = 'INSERT INTO mytable (v_loc) VALUES ('
for v in obj.data.vertices:
    pg_insert += 'POINT({} {} {}),'.format(v.co.x, v.co.y, v.co.z)
pg_insert += ');'
```

Comment: I understand what you did there, but this will result in the vertices being stored, which is nice, but not the polyhedral I was looking for. I have a vertices list and a triangles (faces) list in python, but this is not a polyhedral.

Comment: @GaryNobles while the sql gen is simplified, you can take the vertices and polygon list and use it to define [`POLYHEDRALSURFACE`](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html) data that is stored in a single field. As a polyhedral is the whole object of multiple polys, you would use the entire polygons list to make the surface data. Each polygon item in blender has a list of vertex indices - `v_idx = obj.data.polygons[f].vertices[v] v_loc = obj.data.vertices[v_idx].co`.